# Magento2: creating the registry in controller & getting the same registry in block

Tags: magento2, magento-community

please help me if I m missing something as, I m unable to get the registry in Block from controller..

here is my code in controller to set regitry..

```
$this->_coreRegistry->register('user_id', $userId);
```

below is the code in block to retrieve registry..

```
public function getUserId(){
    return $this->coreRegistry->registry('user_id');
}
```

please help... or if any body knows to store the string in session which is accessible in block please guide me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

### Set at controller

In magento, for create *a registry variable* at **controller** , you should  inject  *\Magento\Framework\Registry* class   at  `__construct()` of that your controller.

**Just like:**

```
   protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
       .....
    ) {
       ...
     $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    ...
    }


/* add your registry varible */
public function AssignMyVariable()
{       
    return $this->_coreRegistry->register('user_id', $userId);
}
```

### Get at block:

Then getting this registry variable ,***you also need to inject registry class at the block class*** .

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
.....
) {
...
$this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
...
}


/* add your registry varible */
public function getUserId(){
    return $this->coreRegistry->registry('user_id');
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I am doing in the same way but no luck.... if I am trying to print that ID in same controller then its working but unable to use this in Block or controller.. pls help

Comment: @Amit, even same i tried, my custom variable is not returned from registry

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be caused by page cache module, specificly by *_isScopePrivate* property. If you setup this property to "yes", your block will be rendered on separate controller - *\Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Render*. The solution for this case is to create separate model responsible for user_id resolving. Then you can inject this model directly in the block.